# How can I create a bootable USB ISO stick without formatting the stick

Tags: usb, iso, format, usb-flash-drive

I know that there are many well-known methods for creating a bootable USB stick, but all these alternatives needs to **format** the USB stick.

What I'm looking for is some alternative method to create an USB bootable stick without the need of formatting it.

That's because I usually have an USB stick that I use to transport files and everything, and I don't like having to backup these files every time I have to load a new ISO to the USB stick.

Comment: Product recommendation questions, including just exists-research, are [off-topic on all StackExchange sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa).

Comment: if you are on windows use EasyBcd it's a good thing

Comment: Just because a question mentioned "software" doesn't make it a product recommendation question.  I've edited the question to remove any mention of software to make it clear that this is a "how can I do this" question.  I found the recommendation below a valuable resource, and would love to have seen more alternative methods if there are any.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this:

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I can confirm that UNetbootin preserved the files on a USB stick when I imaged an ISO on it today.